# What do I put on an "Accepted" line?

Tags: contract-law

I received a letter of intent to sign and the signature block has a line after "Accepted" as though I should put something there.

> <Legal Entity Name>
>
> ACCEPTED: _______________
>
> BY: ______________
>
> Date: ______________

This is new to me. After a cursory search I could not find any info or even any examples of this. What goes there?

Comment: Totally not obvious. Perhaps "Yes", or "No", but not returning it would probably have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I put on an “Accepted” line?

You need to ask the counterparty to clarify that matter for you, and then you make your decision of whether or not it makes sense and is consistent with the purpose of the contract (including your interests therein).

In contracts one is not supposed to *guess*, which is basically what the counterparty is making you do (even if unintentionally). Instead, under contract law the parties are presumed to know and understand the conditions they enter.